# C# Have server see the difference between clients on IP:Port

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcplistener

So let's say I have a server on IP Address A. And two clients on IP Address B using software that is using the TcpClient class. If both clients are listening in two different IPv4 addresses but on the same port. How will a server be able to reply with data to both of the clients using a TcpClient and a networkstream?

It's a bit difficult to try this for me at the moment considering I only have access to one computer at the moment and I can't have two tcplisteners on the same port on one computer.

Thanks

Edited for clarification.

Comment: Umm, you're inverting this. The server is the only one who should be running a `TcpListener` - the clients will simply use `TcpClient` to open a stream to the server, and the server can write data to that stream at any time. As for how TCP works, just read an article or a book - it's not information that's hard to find, and there's little point in posting it on SO. But just the gist: each TCP/IP connection has remote IP address and TCP port, as well as local IP address and TCP port. The client's address and port are used to distinguish connections (see TCP Ephemeral ports).

Comment: I see what you mean but in my case both clients and the server are running listeners because the communicate with eachother. But I could have explained it somewhat better I guess. Also, I think it's a great idea to have it on SO considering the amount of googlers that ends up here.

Comment: Again, that's the problem. Don't have the clients run their own listeners. Just use the TCP stream you have, it's bi-directional.

Comment: But I have to have the clients have their own listeners if I say have a chat application(which I do) and person A writes a message that then the server has to send to all of the connected clients.

Comment: Regarding the lack of multiple computers - that's a major use case of virtual machines.  Just fire up as many servers and clients as your hardware can handle, and have them all talk amongst themselves.

Comment: I could use a virtual machine, or several, but it is something I will setup in the near future as I'm noticing that it will be very good for testing. But was wondering if I could get a quicker answer on SO as my current network line is really slow.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you are asking about. "How does a server reply to a client" - via `socket.Write()`. "How does server see the difference` - it has sockets bound to different clients. Kind of what is explained in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) "*AcceptTcpClient is a blocking method that returns a TcpClient that **you can use to send and receive data***". Could you perhaps clarify your question?

Comment: I apologise, the amount of code I have written for this is quite large. But basically I have a server and several clients. I wrote the code so that when the client connects to the server, I store the IP and the port that the client connects from, and then when the server has data to send back, I use that same IP and port to create a new tcpclient on the server that then sends the data back. But what if I have two clients on the same network that will the have the same public IP? There will be two clients using the same port and public IP. The data will only go to one of them?

Comment: You have to keep the TCP connection open. When the server needs to send a response back to the clients, it just sends it to the sockets it already has. No new connections are initiated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, only use one TcpListener, and do so in the server. The clients should connect to the server, not the other way around. This way, on the clients' computers, you'll be assigned a random available port to communicate with the server.

Second of all, you could use virtual machines to test on a single machine, or run the server and clients on the same computer, that would still work. Good luck!

Comment: But what if the server has to connect back and talk to the client at some random point in time? Wouldn't keeping the stream open be bad on the bandwidth and efficiency?

Comment: @Thomja the server doesn't "connect back", when a client connects in tcp, it's a bidirectional connection. Both the client and the server can send data to each other with only one connection (established by the client)

Comment: @Thomja - keeping the streams open but not sending anything requires minimal resources.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever is right, don't worry about the resource usage. It's minimal. As long as the socket is not  sending any data, there's barely any memory used.

Comment: Ok, but what if I have multiple clients?

TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
stream = client.GetStream();

tcpclient can only be used on one port at a time for one client?

Comment: That's fine, the TcpListener will handle it. You only have to call `tcoListener.AcceptTcpClient()` multiple times to accept multiple clients. The method will return a TcpClient everytime there's a client connecting. For multi client handling, I have a little example project on Github. check it out here: https://github.com/Phyyl/ObooltNet

Comment: @Thomja - each TCP connection is characterized by four pieces of information - `source IP: source Port: destination IP: destination Port`. So long as the entire thing is unique (which it will be) there's no confusion. It's why you don't choose your source port as a client - you let the system grab an unassigned one.

Comment: @Philippe Paré You are using syntax that is waaaay out of my league, I'm just trying to learn something new with this. But I will go through it in more detail later on thanks!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I see, and when is this port chosen? Also, if a random port is chosen, how can the client recieve a response back later on if it turns out that this port is not open on the clients firewall? Thanks!

Comment: @Thomja You should really read up on how TCP works, it's a rather complex topic. The return address is part of the lower-level data being sent (the source ip/port as mentioned by Damien among other things). Firewalls are of no importance in this - the connection is initiated from the client, and that's the only time you care about the firewall. The opened channel is bi-directional.

Comment: @Thomja - again, that's the point of keeping the connection open. The firewall will, by default, be configured to allow the client to make *outgoing* connections using ephemeral ports. Your "the server connects back to the client" is the one that would have issues with firewalls, since it would be an *incoming* connection, and those tend to be the things we worry about (more).

Comment: Thanks to the both of you for making this more clear to me! Really appreciated! I will do some more reading about this.